# iOS 5 Storyboards - Returning to Initial View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

I'm working on an application that uses the new Storyboard functionality in Xcode 4.2

Is there a way of programatically sending a user back to the initial view controller from any point within the application?

For example when a session expires and they need to login again (initial view controller is my login screen)

Comment: Solved by: [[appDelegate.window rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using a `UINavigationController`. Then you can use the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method. You should be able to do this with this line:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // Put YES for animation.
```

You can read more about the `UINavigationController` in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a).

Comment: Its actually a mixture initially its a view controller and depending on types of account it can hit either a navigation controller and then into a tab controller. So you may be on a view, a tab or a table view.  Ideally i'd like to be able to jump back to the initial view controller from any of these locations

Comment: I see. Have you tried the `popToViewController:animated:` method? If you have a reference to your root view controller, this one might work.